# open csv file on notification click in android

Tags: android

4

I want to open csv file when it gets downloaded  on click of the notification.

```
public static void notifyNotification(String title, String description, File file, Context activity) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  getNotificationBuilder(activity, description);


    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } else {
        uri = Uri.parse(file.getPath()); // My work-around for new SDKs, causes ActivityNotFoundException in API 10.
    }
    Intent viewFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    viewFile.setDataAndType(uri, "application/*");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, viewFile, 0);

    builder = builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pay_aw_app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
//                .setTicker("Ticker")
            .setContentText(description)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(createID(), builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Please state what happens when you execute your current code cause it seems okay.

Comment: @GiddyNaya nothing   no response

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function.

```
fun openCSVFile(context: Context, path: String) {

    try {


        var csvIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        csvIntent.setDataAndType(
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".provider", File(path)),
            "text/csv"
        )
        csvIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
        csvIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(csvIntent);


    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        Utility.showToast(context, "Not supported application found.")
        e.printStackTrace()

    }

}
```

You have to just convert it to java

Answer (score 0):

Replace your intent block with below

```
//Make file available via FileProvider
Intent viewFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
viewFile.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file), "text/csv");
viewFile.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
viewFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, viewFile, 0);
```

Add a provider in your manifest

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

--Create a folder **xml** under res folder (res/xml)

--Create a file named **provider_paths.xml** inside xml folder and add the below content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: i have done with these above steps but it's not working